# Launch of My Activity at startup with out using Action_boot_complete

Tags: android

Instead of displaying home screen for the first time I want to display my activity for device setup when device_provisioned == 0.

How can I override the code that launches the home screen activity.

Thanks,

Yousuf

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will have to wait till the boot complete.